# Checkbox state based on text field value

Tags: jquery

I have a search form with many checkboxes with class='cambio', and a hidden field with id #cambio too.

This is how the form works:

1. When a checkbox is checked, his value is sent to this hidden input.
2. This hidden input is disabled by default and get enabled only if a value is set.
3. I get the default value for this field with $_GET['cambio'], so I can keep the form update on page load.

The problem is when I load the page, I get the default values right on my hidden input, but the related checkboxes are all unchecked.

My question is: How I can set these checkboxes to 'checked' only if his value is present on the hidden input?

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
$("input:checkbox.cambio").change(function() {
    var newArr = $("input:checkbox.cambio:checked").map(function() { return this.value; });
    $("#cambio").val(newArr.get());

    if($('#cambio').val() !== "") {
    $('#cambio').prop('disabled', false);
    } else { $('#cambio').prop('disabled', true); }
});
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if($('#cambio').val() !== "") {
    $('#cambio').prop('disabled', false);
    } else { $('#cambio').prop('disabled', true); }
});
```

Note that there is some duplicated code. If you know how to slim down the code, every suggestion is welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: `$('#somecheckbox').prop('checked', true);`

Comment: But how about the ckeckbox get checked if his value match some of the values present on the text input?

Comment: Use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the value and compare it.

Comment: could you give me a example?

Comment: I don't know what you're comparing or what you're comparing it to. The docs page has examples on how to get value of inputs.

Comment: The comparison should be made between the value of the checkbox and the value present in the text field. (The values ​​of the text field are separated by commas.) Thanks!